# How do use catchAll component in yii2 framwork?

Tags: php, yii2

how do use catchAll component in yii2 framwork?

It gives error, when I am configuring as it described in documentation.

```
'catchAll' => [
    'site/offline',
    'h' => 2,
],
```

browser show this message:

> The page isn’t redirecting properly

Comment: Please show the code of your offline action.

Answer (score 0):

Could be you need  a `$h2` param in your controller/action   signature

```
public function actionOffline($h)
{

   if ($h ==2){
      return $this->render('offline_h2');
   }
   return $this->render('offline');
}
```

Comment: @paul  yes  i have tried and work perfectly .. (this is code i used  for my test 
     public function actionOffline($h2)
    {
        var_dump($h2);
        return;
       return $this->render('offline');
    }     so  ... if  you want  you can try your self .. and after    you can rate my answer  as correct  . at least ..  normally a build a proper  code sample for che the OP question and formuale a correct  answer  ...not ever  .. but very frequently ..

Comment: But this doesn't cause the problem the OP met. Having the `h` parameter in the action signature or not doesn't cause the error also.

Comment: if  the OP show other code  i can evaulate  .. for what i know the error could be related  to an improper  .. url format .. and this could happen if the signature don't match   .. .. you have aske if i have tried my code  ...  and i have properly answered ..

Comment: We should be more discreet when we answer questions before having a clear proof that our answers would be helpful to the OP. Just my own opinion.

Comment: your comment is correct  but for my experience  .. the new  User must be lead to the solution  Eespecially with examples .. often even if the example is not perfectly centered the user is induced to provide useful elements to find out his real problem ... if you just limit yourself to some comments on the question asked by the user inviting him to Provide further insights, often the user does not provide topics as clear as when he receives a response even if he is not the exact one he needs. I repeat .. this is for less experienced users.  .. I hope you can understand my point of view.